# Scraping AJAX - loaded website in Python which url should I use

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, api

I have scraped following website: https://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/czech-republic/production/availability/non-usability/non-usability using Selenium. I am scraping all the table data. It works well, but it takes rather a long time to run the script. Thus, I started searching for alternative and came across several topics here on StackOverflow using API to send request to server, but after hours of trying and searching for example I gave up, because I don't get several things:

- How to reverse engineer API to send the right request?
- Which url link should I use?

This is what I came up with:

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.eex-transparency.com/ajax/en/navigation/ajaxGetNavi/12"

data = {
    "id": "16",
    "title": "Czech Republic",
    "url": "https:\\/\\/www.eex-transparency.com\\/homepage\\/power\\/czech-republic",
    "class": "country",
    "description": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "649",
        "title": "Production",
        "url": False,
        "class": "",
        "description": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "650",
            "title": "Capacity",
            "url": False,
            "class": "",
            "description": "",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "651",
                "title": "Installed Capacity",
                "url": "https:\\/\\/www.eex-transparency.com\\/homepage\\/power\\/czech-republic\\/production\\/capacity\\/installed-capacity",
                "class": "",
                "description": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
       }
      ]      
     }


response = requests.get(url, data=data)
file = response.json()
```

In general, maybe someone could explain, what steps should I take in order scrape the latter webpage, I am particularly interested how to find the correct info from Chrome (-> Inspect -> Network -> XHR) and how from the latter info to build `data` variable (that I input into `requests`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scrapy`

**Scrapy**, a fast high-level web crawling & scraping framework for Python.

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/